# Finding ellips equation by focuses and tangent line

Tags: geometry

The Ellips which has focuses in $(±3,0)$ and a tangent line $x+y-5=0$.
I need to find ellips equation.
I've founded these equations

$\frac{x_{0}}{a^2} = \frac{1}{5}, \frac{y_{0}}{b^2} = \frac{1}{5}$

But it gives no benefit to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $2a$ is the length of the major axis of the ellipse and it has $e$ as eccentricity then the focii are at $(\pm ae,0)$ (Assuming center of the ellipse at $(0,0)$ and axes parallel to the bases). So, you have $ae=3$, and since $x+y-5=0$ is a tangent you have some point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the ellipse such that $\dfrac{x_0}{a^2}=\dfrac{y_0}{b^2}=1/5$. Then since $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the ellipse, you have got, $$a^2+b^2=25\Rightarrow \dfrac{2-e^2}{9e^2}=25\Rightarrow e=1/\sqrt{113}$$. You then get your $a,b$ and thus have the equation of the ellipse.